# How To Create Pyramid Bar Chart in R with y-axis labels between the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Below is some R code that generates a bar plot using ggplot, where the bars go off to the left and right, centered at `x = 0`. I would like to take the text on the y axis (the stage names), and place them **in-between** the left and the right bars. Here is the R code creating the graph:

```
library(dplyr)
libary(ggplot2)

# Read data
email_campaign_funnel <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/email_campaign_funnel.csv")

# X Axis Breaks and Labels 
brks <- seq(-15000000, 15000000, 5000000)
lbls = paste0(as.character(c(seq(15, 0, -5), seq(5, 15, 5))), "m")

# Shorten Names
email_campaign_funnel <- email_campaign_funnel %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Stage = gsub('Stage ', '', Stage)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Stage = gsub(' Page', '', Stage)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Stage = gsub('Campaign-', '', Stage))

# Plot
ggplot(email_campaign_funnel, aes(x = Stage, y = Users, fill = Gender)) +   # Fill column
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6) +   # draw the bars
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks,   # Breaks
                       labels = lbls) + # Labels
    coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
    labs(title="Email Campaign Funnel") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
          axis.ticks = element_blank()) +   # Centre plot title
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")  # Color palette
```

Below is a screenshot of a different graph that highlights sort of how I'd like the text to be split in between the bars (I prefer the vertical style of the `ggplot()` graph more so than the horizontal nature of the imaged graph below).

[image]
Any ideas on how to do this in R would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this using `ggarrange` from the `ggpubr` package:

```
gg1 <- email_campaign_funnel %>%
    mutate(Users = if_else(Gender == "Male", Users, 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Stage, Users, fill = Gender)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.6) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks, labels = lbls) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title="Email Campaign Funnel") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Male" = "Red", "Female" = "Blue")) +
    theme(
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

gg2 <- email_campaign_funnel %>%
    filter(Gender == "Male") %>%
    ggplot(aes(Stage, 0, label = Stage)) +
    geom_text() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_void()

gg3 <- email_campaign_funnel %>%
    mutate(Users = if_else(Gender == "Female", Users, 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Stage, Users, fill = Gender)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.6) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks, labels = lbls) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title="Email Campaign Funnel") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Male" = "Red", "Female" = "Blue")) +
    theme(
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())


library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(gg1, gg2, gg3, ncol = 3, common.legend = TRUE, align = "h")
```

[image]

Explanation: The idea is to build the plot separately from the left and right pyramid bar charts and the labels in the middle. We then use `ggpubr::ggarrange` to arrange all three `ggplot2` plot objects in a single row and ensure that axes are properly aligned.

---

### Split horizontal bar chart with labels in the middle

I was interested in seeing how close we can get to the horizontal pyramid bar chart plot you link to. Here is my attempt:

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "Category Group Value
REB Red 39
REB Blue 35
OREB Red 8
OREB Blue 4
DREB Red 31
DREB Blue 31
AST Red 25
AST Blue 21
STL Red 5
STL Blue 5
BLK Red 1
BLK Blue 0
TOV Red 9
TOV Blue 11", header = T)

# Set factor order
df <- df %>% mutate(Category = factor(Category, unique(Category)))

# Build ggplot2 plot objects
library(tidyverse)
gg1 <- df %>%
    filter(Group == "Red") %>%
    ggplot(aes(Category, Value, fill = Group, label = Value)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(colour = "red3", fontface = "bold", nudge_y = 10) +
    theme_void() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red" = "red3", "Blue" = "navyblue"), drop = FALSE) +
    ylim(c(0, round(1.5 * max(df$Value))))

gg2 <- df %>%
    filter(Group == "Red") %>%
    ggplot(aes(Category, 0, label = Category)) +
    geom_text(fontface = "bold") +
    theme_void()

gg3 <- df %>%
    filter(Group == "Blue") %>%
    ggplot(aes(Category, -Value, fill = Group, label = Value)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(colour = "navyblue", fontface = "bold", nudge_y = -10) +
    theme_void() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red" = "red3", "Blue" = "navyblue"), drop = FALSE) +
    ylim(c(round(-1.5 * max(df$Value)), 0))

# Arrange plot objects in 1 column with horizontal scales aligned
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(gg1, gg2, gg3, nrow = 3, common.legend = TRUE, align = "h", heights = c(1, 0.5, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: @Canovice Just out of curiosity: Could you let me know if/how my answer does not address your question. Happy to expand/provide more details. You've reviewed & accepted all questions you asked after this but never got back to this one.

Comment: this was one of the best answers i've gotten on a post. didn't realize i hadn't replied / accepted an answer!

Comment: Hi! Just one thing, I tried to re-create this code and get the numbers and everything but the bars are "invisible" and I have no idea why? Is there smth not included in the code?I'm kinda confused